# JSONObject.toString() converts internal JSONArray as string in Android

Tags: android, json

I am creating a JSON request as followed:

```
JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
request.put("ID", "35");
    request.put("password", "password");
    List<JSONObject> fieldList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        fieldList.add(new JSONObject()
                 .put("unitid", "unitid " + i)
                 .put("price", "Price " + i));
    }

request.put("unitsummary", new JSONObject()
       .put("unitsummarydetail", fieldList)
);

String requestString = request.toString();
```

The value of `requestString` variable should be :

```
{
  "ID": "35",
  "password": "password",
  "unitsummary": {
    "unitsummarydetail": [
      {
        "price": "Price 0",
        "unitid": "unitid 0"
      },
      {
        "price": "Price 1",
        "unitid": "unitid 1"
      },
      {
        "price": "Price 2",
        "unitid": "unitid 2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But it is :

```
{
  "ID": "35",
  "password": "password",
  "unitsummary": {
    "unitsummarydetail": "[{\"unitid\":\"unitid 0\",\"price\":\"Price 0\"}, {\"unitid\":\"unitid 1\",\"price\":\"Price 1\"}, {\"unitid\":\"unitid 2\",\"price\":\"Price 2\"}]"
  }
}
```

It is converting the `unitsummarydetail` as string.
I have tried but didn't find similar issue or any solution on internet.
Is there any issue in my code or this is the behavior of library?

Any ideas or solution code snippets are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: your first json format is not valid

Comment: your fieldList is simple list convert it to JSONArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JSONArray instead of ArrayList.

```
JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
request.put("ID", "35");
request.put("password", "password");
JSONArray fieldList = new JSONArray();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
fieldList.put(new JSONObject() .put("unitid", "unitid " + i)      .put("price", "Price " + i));
}
request.put("unitsummary", new JSONObject() .put("unitsummarydetail",   fieldList) );
String requestString = request.toString();
```

Output:

> {"ID":"35","password":"password","unitsummary":{"unitsummarydetail":[{"unitid":"unitid
>   0","price":"Price 0"},{"unitid":"unitid 1","price":"Price
>   1"},{"unitid":"unitid 2","price":"Price 2"}]}}

Answer (score 2):

change your code

from

```
request.put("unitsummary", new JSONObject()
   .put("unitsummarydetail", fieldList));
```

to

```
request.put("unitsummary", new JSONObject()
   .put("unitsummarydetail", new JSONArray(fieldList)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Crazy !!!!

```
    JsonArray treatIdArray = new JsonArray(); // this one will result string : "["id", "id"]"


    JSONArray treatIdArray = new JSONArray(); // this one will result array : ["id", "id"]
```

They are 2 different Json, lol, com.google.gson.JsonArray vs org.json.JSONArray and it took me almost a day. Oh my God !!!!

Answer (score 0):

you could create a JSON array unitsummarydetail and add all the json objects unitsummary in a for loop